# How can i delete multiple specific folders from a directory with a bat file?

Tags: batch-file, delete-file

Kind of a continuation of a previous question, but i have 570 folders, where some of them contain another folder called "autosaves", and i would like to create a bat file which finds these and deletes them (the autosaves folder, not the actual folder which contains the autosaves folder), but after a little trial and error to no avail, I figured I would come back here as i got a very good result last time.

So basically.

```
 MainFolder
 ---ExampleFolder1   (does not contain an autosaves folder)
 ---ExampleFolder2   (contains an autosaves folder)
 ---ExampleFolder3   (contains an autosaves folder)
 ---ExampleFolder4   (does not contain an autosaves folder)
```

---

I need this to become:

```
 MainFolder
 ---ExampleFolder1   (does not contain an autosaves folder)
 ---ExampleFolder2   (does not contain an autosaves folder)
 ---ExampleFolder3   (does not contain an autosaves folder)
 ---ExampleFolder4   (does not contain an autosaves folder)
```

---

so if anyone knows that would be great :)

Comment: Based upon your provided information, I cannot see any reason why you could not have made a basic command change from the last answer tou received! ```For /D %%G In ("MainFolder\*") Do RD /S /Q "%%~G\autosaves" 2>NUL```

Comment: I tried, cause i thought of this as well, but i really dont know anything about batch coding. tried to research it a little, but the documentation was very confusing, and as i don't know which parameters or extensions work with each other, this was very hard, so i just went and asked here instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
FOR /f "delims=" %%b IN ('dir /s /b /ad "u:\your files" ^|sort /r') DO IF /i "%%~nxb"=="autosave" ECHO RD /s /q "%%b"
```

where `u:\your files` gets replaced by your directory.

Find all directorynames in full, sort them in reverse order and if the leaf is named `autosave`, remove it.

The `rd` command is merely `echo`ed for testing purposes. When verified, remove the `echo` keyword to activate.

The list is sorted in reverse order so that any `autosave` directory containing other directories is  processed after those subdirectories, hence the code should not attempt to delete a subdirectory of an already-deleted directory.

**NB** This code will remove all subdirectories named `autosave` in the tree, so a subdirectory `example\something\anotherthing\autosave\somethingelse` will be lopped after `anotherthing`

Comment: Oh wow that worked! (I think, it at least removed the "autosaves" folder from 3 of the confirmed places with a folder like it, so i'm assuming it did all the others as well), But Anyway thank you very much :D, worked like a charm